# Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized Publishing maven artifact to gcp artifact registry

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have copied the `tekton-hub` gradle task and modify the environment variable and volume-mount for GOOGLE_CREDENTIAL as below

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Task
metadata:
  name: gradle
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "0.3"
  annotations:
    tekton.dev/pipelines.minVersion: "0.17.0"
    tekton.dev/displayName: Gradle
    tekton.dev/categories: Build Tools
    tekton.dev/tags: build-tool
    tekton.dev/platforms: "linux/amd64,linux/s390x,linux/ppc64le"
spec:
  description: >-
    This Task can be used to run a Gradle build.

  workspaces:
    - name: source
      description: The workspace consisting of the gradle project.
    - name: gradle-config
      description: The workspace consisting of the custom gradle properties provided by the user.
      optional: true
  params:
    - name: GRADLE_IMAGE
      description: Gradle base image.
      type: string
      default: docker.io/library/gradle:7.6-jdk8@sha256:ebda657f66e04cfa9f152896b4fa70bea4b80561a836adddca3ed85d622f8898
    - name: PROJECT_DIR
      description: The directory containing build.gradle
      type: string
      default: "."
    - name: TASKS
      description: 'The gradle tasks to run (default: build)'
      type: array
      default:
        - build    
    - name: GCP-SECRET
      type: string
      description: name of the secret holding the gcp-token
      default: gcp-secret
  steps:
    - name: gradle-tasks
      image: $(params.GRADLE_IMAGE)
      env:
        - name: GRADLE_USER_HOME
          value: "/home/gradle"
        - name: GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS
          valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: gcp-secret
                key: gcp-config
      
      workingDir: $(workspaces.source.path)/$(params.PROJECT_DIR)
      args:
        - "$(params.TASKS)"
      script: |
        #!/usr/bin/env bash
        cat /etc/gcp-secret/gcp-config
        export GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS=/etc/gcp-secret/gcp-config
        if [[ "$(workspaces.gradle-config.bound)" == "true" ]]; then
          echo "gradle-config workspace is bound"
          if [[ -f $(workspaces.gradle-config.path)/gradle.properties ]]; then
            echo "copying gradle.properties to /home/gradle"
            cp "$(workspaces.gradle-config.path)/gradle.properties" /home/gradle
          fi
        fi

        cmd="gradle $*"
        echo "Running gradle task with command below"
        echo "$cmd"
        eval "$cmd"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /home/gradle
          name: empty-dir
        - name: gcp-secret
          mountPath: /etc/gcp-secret
          readOnly: true
  volumes:
      - name: empty-dir
        emptyDir: {}
      - name: gcp-secret
        secret:
          secretName: gcp-secret
```

The `cat /etc/gcp-secret/gcp-config` does print the file as below

[image]

**Pipeline**

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: Pipeline
metadata:
  name: ft-common
  namespace: fetebird-tekton
spec:
  description: >-
    Clone a git repository. This example pipeline demonstrates the following:
    How to use the git-clone catalog Task
  params:
    - name: REPO_URL
      type: string
      description: The git repository URL to clone from.
    - name : GRADLE_IMAGE
      type: string
      description: Dockcer image for gradle.
    - name : GCP-SECRET
      type: string
      description: Gcp secret.

  workspaces:
    - name: shared-data
      description: |
        This workspace will receive the cloned git repo and be passed
        to the next Task for the repo's README.md file to be read.
  tasks:
    - name: git-clone
      taskRef:
        name: git-clone
      workspaces:
        - name: output
          workspace: shared-data
      params:
        - name: url
          value: "$(params.REPO_URL)"
        - name: deleteExisting
          value: "true"
    - name: gradle-clean-build-publish
      taskRef:
        name: gradle
      runAfter: ["git-clone"]  # Wait until the clone is done before building the java project.
      workspaces:
        - name: source
          workspace: shared-data
      params:
        - name: TASKS
          value:
            - clean
            - build
            - test
            - publish
        - name: GRADLE_IMAGE
          value: "$(params.GRADLE_IMAGE)"
        - name: GCP-SECRET
          value: "$(params.GCP-SECRET)"
```

**Pipeline-run**

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: ft-common-run
  namespace: fetebird-tekton
spec:
  pipelineRef:
    name: ft-common
  podTemplate:
    securityContext:
      fsGroup: 65532
  workspaces:
    - name: shared-data
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: fetebird-common-pvc
  params:
    - name: REPO_URL
      value: git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/common.git
    - name: GRADLE_IMAGE
      value: docker.io/library/gradle:jdk17-alpine@sha256:e80d3108c319eaeef966eefdfd075fdaa44201c8fb6730532a16555426c61dbd
    - name: GCP-SECRET
      value: gcp-secret
  taskRunSpecs:
    - pipelineTaskName: git-clone
      taskServiceAccountName: git-service-account
    - pipelineTaskName: gradle-clean-build-publish
      taskServiceAccountName: gcp-service-account
```

**Exception**

```
2023-09-12T08:05:29.593615030Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2023-09-12T08:05:29.596112191Z 
2023-09-12T08:05:29.598332414Z * What went wrong:
2023-09-12T08:05:29.602566107Z Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenRepository'.
2023-09-12T08:05:29.603032947Z > Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'maven'
2023-09-12T08:05:29.603119108Z    > Could not PUT 'https://australia-southeast2-maven.pkg.dev/fetebird-cicd/common/fete/bird/common/0.0.0/common-0.0.0.jar'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
2023-09-12T08:05:29.603149620Z
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/etc/gcp-secret/gcp-config`

instead of

`GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS`

`export GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS=/etc/gcp-secret/gcp-config`